# error=13, Permission denied when adding event in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

Suddenly, and for no apparent reason, whenever I try to add an event to a form element, like a button, in codenameone I get an error:

> Cannot run program /path/to/project/src/theme.res: error=13,
>   Permission denied

This worked fine for several days before now. But now I get the error every time. I tried to create a brand new project from scratch and still get the error. What is really weird is that the /path/to/project/ is for the *original* project, not the new one! And when it appears for this case, it is file not found instead of permission denied. (Both files ARE there.)

I have searched all over the net and stack exchange and can't find any other reference to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. It happened after I deleted a project's files without removing the project from NetBeans first. Not sure why that caused it but that is the only thing I can think of because the theme.res file that "could not be found" was for the project that I had deleted.

For some reason the CN1 designer thinks that your theme.res file is the NetBeans executable.

To fix this, open the designer and click on File -> Setup Netbeans, then find your netbeans executable and select it. For me (on linux) it was

> home/user/netbeans-8.1/bin/netbeans

[image: Setup Netbeans dialog]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!